# observable array length is always zero

Tags: knockout.js

Here is the js:

```
var view = function(){
    self.arry = ko.observable();

    self.arry(ko.mapping.fromJS([{prop:'Test'},{prop:'Test'}]));

    console.log(self.arry().length);       
}
var v = new view();
```

The observable array length is always zero. How do I get the correct length?

Edit:
Updated the JS and fixed the errors. 
http://jsfiddle.net/eRHTv/

```
var view = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.arry = ko.observableArray();

  self.load_items = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    self.arry(ko.mapping.fromJS([{prop:'Test'},{prop:'Test'}]));
    }, 100);
  }
  self.no_items_visible = ko.computed(function(){
     return (self.arry().length == 0);
  });

  self.load_items();


  ko.applyBindings(self);
}

var v = new view();
```

When you run this, no items div will always be visible and if you do self.arry = data, the view won't get updated.

Comment: There are a lot things missing or wrong with this - you should probably check out the interactive tutorials at knockoutjs.com

Comment: Question probably won't help future visitors. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing is: You're never defining the variable `self`:

```
var self = this;
```

Second: ko.mapping.fromJS() returns an observable array if the input is an array:

```
self.arry = ko.mapping.fromJS(...);
```

In total:

```
var view = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.arry = ko.mapping.fromJS([ {prop:'Test1'}, {prop:'Test1'} ]);

    console.log(self.arry().length);
}

var v = new view();
```

Comment: The reason for self.arry(ko.mapping.fromJS()) is that the view will update then. By doing that, self.arry().length always return greater than 0.

Comment: If you need to update an existing observableArray with the values of another observableArray, you need to pass the array, no the observable: `self.arry( ko.mapping.fromJS([ {prop:'Test1'}, {prop:'Test2'} ])() /* <--- */ );`

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to correct the issues using Niko's changes http://jsfiddle.net/eRHTv/22/

Answer (score 3):

This post explains why the length of an observable array is always equals 0.
In fact, an observable array (returned by ko.observableArray(...)) is a function. Any function has a length property.

More here:

https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/4

So, you should always use: myObservableArray().length instead of myObservableArray.length.